# Root taking ownership of generated files. Plesk CP

Tags: permissions

I hope someone here can offer me some guidence.

I have recently switched all my accounts from cPanel / WHM to Plesk and part of this was an active development of a Magento 2.3.2 site.

Since moving onto the new system I am having issues with the generated folder being owned by Root. I have followed Magento's steps in terms of ownership and groupings which solved the issue in the var/cache folder but the issue is still present in the generated folder.

Having spent nearly 18 hours on this one issue I am about to pull my hair out. Anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Comment: which user is your cron job running as? should be file owner.